# Access column in dataframe by variable

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyr

I want to access a column in a dataframe. But the name of the column is saved as a variable.

```
library(tidyr)
p <- column_name
df <- separate(df, p, into = c("a", "b"), sep = "\\*")
```

Is there any workaround for that?

Comment: Try `?separate` perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `separate_`, which is the standard evaluation version of `separate` and can accept *Name of column to split, **as string.***:

```
df <- data.frame(A = "a*b")
df
#    A
#1 a*b

library(tidyr)
p <- "A"
df %>% separate_(p, into=c("x", "y"), sep="\\*")

#  x y
#1 a b
```